# using colour in a cnn

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, torch

Everything worked great at first. I was pushing 4 screenshots at a time in batches of 64, with pixel dimensions of 80, 64 = torch.Size([64, 4, 80, 64])

However i wish to use colour instead of grayscale, with colour i get [64, 4, 80, 64, 3]
which leads to

```
RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d, but got input of size: [64, 4, 80, 64, 3]
```

my cnn is below,

```
self.representation = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=4, out_channels=32, kernel_size=8, stride=4),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=24, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=24, out_channels=24, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(24),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=24, out_channels=8, kernel_size=2, stride=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(8),
        )
```

ive tried changing a few numbers in my cnn, but i suspect i need to do something else.

Ive seen 1 suggestion which i hate, basically saying you should pass in the 3 different colours (red,green,blue) seperatley.... but into the same neural network? or 3 different ones?.... and then what, average out their answers? (also given that all obstacles to avoid are red, and the charachter is green then i fear were seperating information that shouldnt be seperated)

what could i do in this situation?

#########################################

ps

there is a full copy of my script here. = https://github.com/tgmjack/public-dropbox
the game, agent n neural network are a bit big to cut down to something copy and paste here.

Comment: You can turn colour images into grayscale (e.g. with [open cv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html)) and pass them into your network

Comment: I know, it allready was grey and everything was fine. i want to try colour... but not sure how

Comment: I guess that the issue comes from your "4 screenshots", you should just put image batches of size [64, 80, 64, 3] as input

Comment: I am not so familiar with pytorch, but couldn't you transform your input image from 80x64x3 to 240 x 64 pixels, putting all channels next to each other.